# Is it possible to specify a timeout for `git clone` operation?

Tags: linux, git, version-control

I use `git clone` in scripts, and I want to timeout the operation, if it takes longer than, say, `N` minutes to complet.

The reason is that some repositories are more than 5GB in size (even with `--depth 1`), which can take more than 30 minutes to download, depending on the load. I want to **ignore** these repositories.

Since `git` provides no way to check the size of a repository before cloning, the only solution I can think of is to specify a timeout for `git clone`. Is that possible?

Comment: Seems like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Have you actually tried finding a way to get the repo size? There are posts that show how to do that with varying degrees of accuracy. Have you researched any of those methods to see whether they are adequate for solving your underlying problem?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+timeout

Comment: Also see https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-httplowSpeedLimithttplowSpeedTime

Comment: For local development a `--depth=1` is not applicable, what we are doing is leaving out the blobs. So you still have full history, all branches, but no files (those get fetched on demand). If you use
`git clone --filter=blob:none`, you fetch ususally only a fraction, which helps you reducing download size drastically, additionally to setting a timeout.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest a method:

1. `git clone` with `--depth 1` or clone single branch: `git clone [remote url] --branch [branch_name] --single-branch [folder]` (if needed)
2. Get output of `clone` command, ex:

   Cloning into 'www-gitlab-com'...
   .....

   Receiving objects: **1% (123/624541), 74.61 MiB | 8.14 MiB/s, done**.
3. You can watch command output for a seconds, and if you see "1% ... 1.2 GiB" you know you're in trouble with large repo, and you can cancel it

Comment: Isn't `--depth 1` the same as `--single-branch`?

Comment: @Shuzheng https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone#Documentation/git-clone.txt---depthltdepthgt
--depth :Create a shallow clone with a history truncated to the specified number of commits. Implies --single-branch unless --no-single-branch is given to fetch the histories near the tips of all branches

Comment: Thank you. Are you sure `--single-branch` is needed when `--branch` is specified. Doesn’t `--branch` imply the other?

Comment: The OP didn't ask about a shallow clone, they asked about a git timeout. Git operations don't take a "--timeout" flag as one might expect. You should instead use the git config options listed in their docs: If the HTTP transfer speed is less than http.lowSpeedLimit for longer than http.lowSpeedTime seconds, the transfer is aborted. Can be overridden by the GIT_HTTP_LOW_SPEED_LIMIT and GIT_HTTP_LOW_SPEED_TIME environment variables. See https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config for more details.